# How to get the horizontal-card-footer div right below other div and not at right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to have a structure like this:

[image]

But its not working, the image, date, title and subtitle are ok, but then do you know how to put the Image title right below the image and the view and save links below the other texts with the same margin-left of 1rem?

I have here the Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tyyj57gs/6/, the issue should be because the horizontal-card div have display flex but Im not having sucess solving that issue.

Html:

```
<div class="container pb-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="horizontal-card">

        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100"/>
        <div class="horizontal-card-body">
          <span class="card-text">Date</span>
          <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
          <span class="card-text">Subtitle</span>
        </div>
          <div class="horizontal-card-footer">
          <span>Image Title</span>
          <a class="card-text status">#View</a>
          <a class="card-text status">#Save</a>

        </div>


      </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.horizontal-card{
  display: flex;
  border:1px solid gray;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
  img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;

  }
  .horizontal-card-body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left:1rem;
  }


}
```

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/Lyt9ne4e/

Comment: The image that you uploaded is how you would like the end result right? I am doing it for you :)

Comment: @ovokuro I suggest you post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version of the image. Let me know if there are any issues, I have used position absolute for the footer's position.

For the SCSS version of the CSS refer the fiddle, else refer the snippet below!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

```css
.horizontal-card {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.horizontal-card img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  border-bottom: 30px solid orange;
}
.horizontal-card .horizontal-card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
.horizontal-card .horizontal-card-footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.horizontal-card .horizontal-card-footer span {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.horizontal-card .horizontal-card-footer a {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container pb-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="horizontal-card">

        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
        <div class="horizontal-card-body">
          <span class="card-text">Date</span>
          <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
          <span class="card-text">Subtitle</span>
        </div>
        <div class="horizontal-card-footer">
          <span>Image Title</span>
          <a class="card-text status">#View</a>
          <a class="card-text status">#Save</a>

        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @ovokuro Why not mix it, he is applying flex only for one container right? I mean the parent container is still a normal one

Comment: I guess it could create problems because it is taken out of the flow, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/3t1t3qxs/1/

Comment: @ovokuro Correct me if I'm wrong, but OP is using pixels for defining the image, so I am assuming the content should also be of a fixed height! if you use a flexbox, how will the image get resized???

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP wants, perhaps they could clarify. Using flexbox instead of position we can do this --> https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/8ccvL5b7/1/

Comment: @ovokuro Please ask in the question comments tagging them, Thanks!

Comment: I have to agree with @ovokuro here, since this can be done with the existing Flexbox, start using absolute positioning and fixed border heights to compensate for making space for the title etc. is a really bad solution, and it prevent having a good responsive one.

Answer (score 2):

I did this by using `display:inline-block` instead of the flex box you had. The sections are broken into two `rows`. Add style as you wish.

HTML:

```
<div class="card">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="innerLeft">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100"/>
    </div>      
    <div class="innerRight">
      <div class="horizontal-card-footer">
        <span class="card-text">Date</span>
        <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
        <span class="card-text">Subtitle</span>            
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="innerLeft">
      <p>Image Title</p>          
    </div>
    <div class="innerRight">
      <a class="card-text status">#View</a>
      <a class="card-text status">#Save</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 max-width:800px;
}
img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
.innerLeft {
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:-4px;
 vertical-align:top;
 width:30%;
 text-align:center;
 padding:5px;
}
.innerRight {
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 width:70%;
 text-align:left;
 padding:5px;
}
.card-text {
 display:inline-block;
}
```

FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/tyyj57gs/9/

Answer (score 2):

You can create the layout you want using `flexbox`.

In the snippet below I have restructured your `.horizontal-card` into `.card-left` and `.card-right`.

```css
.horizontal-card {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card-left,
.card-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-right {
  width: 100%;
}

.card-left span {
  background: orange;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.horizontal-card-body,
.horizontal-card-footer {
  padding-left: 1em;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.horizontal-card-footer {
  /* Add to ensure the footer is pinned to the bottom of the card */
  margin-top: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container pb-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="horizontal-card">

        <div class="card-left">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
          <span>Image Title</span>
        </div>

        <div class="card-right">
          <div class="horizontal-card-body">
            <span class="card-text">Date</span>
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <span class="card-text">Subtitle</span>
          </div>
          <div class="horizontal-card-footer">
            <a class="card-text status">#View</a>
            <a class="card-text status">#Save</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container pb-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="horizontal-card">

            <div class="card-left">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
              <span>Image Title</span>
            </div>

            <div class="card-right">
              <div class="horizontal-card-body">
                <span class="card-text">Date</span>
                <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
                <span class="card-text">I am a card with a longer subtitle. I am a card with a longer subtitle. I am a card with a longer subtitle. I am a card with a longer subtitle. </span>
              </div>
              <div class="horizontal-card-footer">
                <a class="card-text status">#View</a>
                <a class="card-text status">#Save</a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container pb-4">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <div class="horizontal-card">

                <div class="card-left">
                  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
                  <span>Image Title</span>
                </div>

                <div class="card-right">
                  <div class="horizontal-card-body">
                    <span class="card-text">Date</span>
                    <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
                    <span class="card-text"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="horizontal-card-footer">
                    <a class="card-text status">#View</a>
                    <a class="card-text status">#Save</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
```